# match if does not include string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to append `.js` extension to all import statements where the file path to be imported starts with a `.`. For example:

```
import { LocalConf } from "./database/LocalConf";
import * as mariadb from "mariadb";
import { Errors } from "./util/Errors";
```

gets transformed to

```
import { LocalConf } from "./database/LocalConf.js";
import * as mariadb from "mariadb";
import { Errors } from "./util/Errors.js";
```

This is the js command I am running:

```
let newData = data.replace(/(import .*? from\s+['"])(\..*?[^\.js])(?=['"])/g, '$1$2.js')
```

Unfortunately `[^\.js]` matches a single character, and not a `.js` string. because of that,

```
import { Errors } from "./util/Errors";
```

never gets `.js` appeneded.

How can I match `.js` string instead of just single characters?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```js
function addExtension(path) {
  if (path.contains('from "./')) {
    return path + ".js";
  }

  return path;
}
```